# Send cURL command from R

Tags: r, rest, rcurl

mailerLite is a SaaS that manages contacts and sends email. I am trying to use their API to add content to my account.

Their API is built on HTTP and it is RESTful. According to their documentation [here](https://developers.mailerlite.com/reference#segments-1), I can see how I have segmented my list. There is a PHP and cURL example:

curl -v https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/segments 
-H "X-MailerLite-ApiKey: my-api-key"

This works successfully from the Terminal prompt on my Mac.
Now I wish to do the same thing from R.

I tried this:

```
apiKey <- "my-api-key"
result <- GET("https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/segments", add_headers(Authorization = paste("X-MailerLite-ApiKey", apiKey)))
result
# Status 401: Unauthorized
```

Also, I am confused about the differences between the R packages: RCurl, httr, curl, and crul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try

```
GET("https://api.mailerlite.com/api/v2/segments", add_headers(`X-MailerLite-ApiKey` = apiKey))
```